# Could not create credential for cloudant db on bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, credentials, cloudant

We created a Cloudant DB on Bluemix, but failed to create its credential. It shows an error as below:

```
Code: BXNIM0424E, Message: Identity has too many policies, Details: Policy cannot be granted because identity 'IBMid-XXXX’ reached the policy limit. PAP error response is: '{"trace":"bss-xxxxxxxxxx”,”errors":[{"code":"request_not_processed","message":"Exceeded maximum policies quota (10500) for account xxxxxxx.”}],”status_code":422}'
```

How can we fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The policy limits are defined here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/iam?topic=iam-iam_limits as well as how to request increasing them if that is needed.

Here is some documentation for the API to remove policies, as well:  https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/iam-policy-management#delete-a-policy-by-id

Answer (score 0):

That seems like an issue specific to your account. If you have an issue with your account, please open a case via https://cloud.ibm.com/unifiedsupport/cases/add.
You can also find health checks of services: https://estado.eu-de.bluemix.net/internalstatus